# Retrieving all html between p tags using JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

So here's the scenario. I have a large html file that I would like to scrape using JSoup. I am new to this and I have been going through some tutorials and the API references. I have the following block of html.

```
<p><a name="bob"></a>
<table class='schedules'>
<tr><td  align='center' colspan="5"><b>Bob the Builder</b><br>
<a href="blah blah" class='tiny'>Blah Blah Blah</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class='bk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='bm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='nm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class='bk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='bk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='nm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class='bk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='bm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class='bm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><!--<td class='whoohaa'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td>--><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='cc'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='cc'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td></tr>
<tr></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='nm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">Blah</a></td><td class='nm'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td><td class='sk'><a href="random/randomUrl.htm">blah</a></td></tr>
</table>
</p>
```

Now there are many more of these blocks following a similar pattern whereby (in the first line) the name attribute changes (from "bob" to something else). What I would like to do is firstly be able to select the "bob" p block and then retrieve all the html until the terminating p block in the last line.

I have attempted the following:

```
Elements innerStuff = doc.select("a:contains(bob) ~ *");
```

But it only gives me links with href atrributes, which I guess is the what will be expected. However, I'm struggling to see how else I can solve this problem?

Your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straitforward way to select the a tag based on its name attribute would be to do:

```
doc.select("a[name=bob]")
```

From there, you should be able to navigate to the elements you want using parent() (to get the p tag containing the link) for example (you'll need to call first() before to get the first (and only) element matching the selector):

```
doc.select("a[name=bob]").first().parent()
```

One problem though: the parsed HTML document is different from the original HTML:
Here's the original HTML structure:

```
p
    a[name=bob]
    table
        ...
```

Here's how the parsed HTML looks like:

```
p
    a[name=bob]
table
    ...
p
```

So, starting from the link tag, and to get that table's element, you'll need to go up one level (to the paragraph) and grab the next element:

```
doc.select("a[name=bob]").first().parent().nextElementSibling()
```

Comment: What a legend! :) Appreciate it.